# NextJS 13/14 Sever Component Code Runs Twice on Page Load with router.replace in Production

Tags: next.js, next.js13, next-router

#### Summary

Hello,

I have a server component which processes some data that then gets sent to the client. Let's say the route is `/test`. On initial page load the data gets processed as expected, but when `router.replace` is called client side on the same route (`/test`), in this case inside a `useEffect`, the server component code reruns and sends newly processed data to the client.

To note this only happens with production builds. `next dev` behaves as expected.

Why is that the case? Is it expected behavior and is it possible not to trigger that second rerender?

Below is a simplified version of the code:

```
server component test/page.tsx
------
export default function ProductPage() {
  console.log('processing...');
  return (
    <ClientContent>
  );
}

client component ClientContent
----
export default function ClientContent() {
  useEffect(() => {
    router.replace('/test'):
  }, [])
  return (<></>);
}
```

My expectation is that the page gets cached on initial load and calling router.replace on the same route would not trigger anything.